# Шрифты для android

Tags: android, шрифты, дизайн

Доброго времени суток.
Стал вопрос какие шрифты можно использовать по android -
google сразу же подсказывает код

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/BaroqueScript.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baroque_script_sample);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Интересует какие форматы шрифтов лучше использовать,  с какими шрифтами меньше подводных камней .... в общем прошу поделится опытом, меня спрашивает дизайнер ( она раньше не рисовала дизайн для android ), мне соответственно с этим работать, поэтому хотелось бы заранее подстраховаться )

Заранее спасибо за любые советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На андроиде работают только шрифты формата `.ttf`. Может быть поддерживаются и другие форматы с помощью каких-нибудь библиотек, но я в этом не уверен.

И ещё вот такой нюанс: если вы будете использовать шрифты в приложении, то **обязательно** пропишите в манифесте минимальную версию sdk 10, иначе при загрузке шрифта программа будет вылетать с сообщением "Native Typeface cannot be made" в логах.

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически - можно любые (если не волнует вопрос лицензионной чистоты). Практически - дизайнеру нужно учитывать, что замена шрифтов в системных контролах требует ручной работы погроммиста.

Answer (score 1):

В доках нет инфы о том, какие форматы поддерживаются. Но...
TTF поддерживается. Подержка OTF добавлена в 1.6, но частично. С TTF тоже не всё хорошо.
Так что, лучше ttf использовать.

p.s. если будете использовать нестандартрные шрифты, чтобы по сто раз не менять программно их, то лучше свои компоненты написать, унаследовав их от стандартных.

p.p.s. и не забывать про возможные утечки памяти. Я [здесь](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/10/22/3320/) про это писал.